# Create a background thread that executes a command every 4hrs

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to figure out how to use a background thread to execute a command ever 4hrs.

I have never created anything like this before so have only been reading about it so far.. One of the things I have read are this

"Threads tie up physical memory and critical system resources"

So in that case would it be a bad idead to have this thread that checkes the time then executes my method... or is there a better option, I have read about GCD (Grand Central Dispatch) but I am not sure if this is applicable as I think its more for concurrent requests? not something that repeats over and over again checking the time..

Or finally is there something I have completely missed where you can execute a request every 4hrs?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a max time background processes are allowed to run (10 min) which would make your approach difficult. Your next best attempt is to calculate the next event as save the times tamp somewhere. Then if the app is executed at or after that event it can carry out whatever action you want.

This might help: 
http://www.audacious-software.com/2011/01/ios-background-processing-limits/

Comment: I think what he/she meant was 'how to create a thread and schedule a timer after 4 hours from now'.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it would be good to make use of a time stamp and post a notification for when the time reaches for hours from now.

Multithreading is not a good means to do this because essentially you would be running a loop for four hours eating clock cycles. Thanks to the magic of operating systems this would not eat up an entire core or anything silly like that however it would be continuously computed if it was allowed to run. This would be a vast waste of resources so it is not allowed. GCD was not really meant for this kind of thing. It was meant to allow for concurrency to smooth out UI interaction as well as complete tasks more efficiently, a 4hr loop would be inefficent. Think of concurrency as a tool for something like being able to interact with a table while its content is being loaded or changed. GCD blocks make this very easy when used correctly. GCD and other multithreading abilities give tools to do calculations in the background as well as interact with databases and deal with requests without ever affecting the users experience. Many people whom are much smarter then me have written exstensively on what multithreading/multitasking is and what it is good for. In a way posting a message for a time would be method of multitasking without the nastiness of constantly executing blocks through GCD to wait for the 4 hr time period, however it is possible to do this. You could execute a block that monitored for time less then the max length of a threads lifetime then when the threads execution is over dispatch it again until the desired time is achieved. This is a bad way of doing this. Post a notification to the notification center, its easy and will accomplish your goal without having to deal with the complexity of multithreading yourself.

You can post a notification request observing for a time change and it will return its note, however this requires you application be active or in the background. I can not guarantee the OS wont kill your application however if it is nice and quiet with a small memory footprint in "background" state its notification center request will remain active and function as intended.